# How serious is the 125 °C limit on an NTC thermistor?

Tags: temperature, thermistor, maximum-ratings

I'm measuring a temperature for use in a thermal cutoff circuit at probably ~100 °C. Temperature exceeds 100 °C, microcontroller kills the power to it.  Nothing novel here, but I'm not certain of the thermal dynamics of the situation; how hot will it overshoot to after I cut power.

SMT NTC thermistors are rated to 125 °C pretty universally; and their datasheets tend to do a hard cutoff of the curves at that point. Unlikely it would get that hot, but not impossible. So the question becomes, just how absolute is that absolute max?  If I get to 135..140 °C will an NTC thermistor continue thermisting, and return to its original base state, or is that going to do it permanent damage?

Comment: Try it at a limit of 100 degC to see what happens. Heat transfer is usually equivalent to a 1st order system with no overshoot.

Comment: You should bear in mind the fact standard FR4 PCBs are only rated to operate at ~120°C and many solders melt around 190°C so the thermistor isn't the only limit on temperature!

Answer (score 10):

Absolute maximums are not an absolute physical limitation; they are a statement from the manufacturer that performance and reliability beyond that value is not guaranteed.

If you exceed an absolute maximum, it's entirely possible the component will still function normally, but also entirely possible that it will be damaged or destroyed. In the case of a thermistor, it may continue to function, but its linearity may be altered, so it no longer conforms to the specifications of the datasheet (among other potential unwanted changes).

Comment: A little more can be read into from the solderability spec; obviously it must be able to reach the 260°C or whatever for some time and cycles, and still meet performance back within the rated range. How much *additional* time you could spend at such temperatures (i.e. beyond 125°C), remains an open question.

Answer (score 5):

Like Andy aka commented, in many cases there won't be such a high overshoot in a heating system. It would mainly occur if you have a large thermal mass that is heated beyond 125°C, and the NTC is behind insulation so that heat takes time to conduct to it.

But if your tests indicate an overshoot, there is no reason not to play it safe: 150°C and even 200°C rated SMD NTC thermistors are easily available from multiple suppliers. E.g. Murata NCU18WF104J6SRB for 150°C or Littelfuse MM103J1K for 220°C.